# Enter numbers, display highest, lowest, average, and number of numbers entered. Use a menu

Tags: c

My groups assignment is to make a program that allows the user to enter as many numbers as they want, and the program will then tell you the highest number entered, lowest entered, the average, total numbers entered, and the average. We must use a menu.

We have the menu written. We have most of our computing code inside Case A (we must use letters) to calculate the stuff. But we don't know how to make the program repeat. If you're done entering numbers and say N to "Would you like to enter another number", the program just closes.

Also, how would you compute the total?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define pause system("pause")
#define cls system("cls")
#define pause system("pause")
#define flush fflush(stdin)
#include <ctype.h> // contains toupper

main(){

int num, count = 0, high = 0, low = 0, total = 0;
float avg;
char choice = ' ', again;

printf("\t\t      =====================\n");
printf("\t\t      ==    MAIN MENU    ==\n");
printf("\t\t      =====================\n");
printf("\t\tA. Enter a number.\n");
printf("\t\tB. Display the highest number.\n");
printf("\t\tC. Display the lowest number.\n");
printf("\t\tD. Display the average of all numbers.\n");
printf("\t\tE. Display how many numbers were entered.\n");
printf("\t\tQ. Quit.\n\n\n");
printf("Enter your selection: ");
scanf("%c", &choice);


    switch (choice) {
    case 'A':
        do {
            printf("Enter a number: ");
            scanf("%i", &num);
            if (count = 0)  {
                high = num;
                low = num;
            }
            else
            if (num > high)
                num = high;
            if (num < low)
                num = low;
            count++;

            printf("Do you want to enter another number? (Y/N):  ");
            scanf("%c", &again);
        } while (again != 'N');
        break;
    case 'B':
        if (count == 0) { printf("Please enter a number first.\n\n"); 
            }
        else printf("The highest number is %i\n\n", high);
        break;
    case 'C':
        if (count == 0) printf("Please enter a number first.\n\n");
        else printf("The lowest number is %i\n\n", low);
        break;
    case 'D':
        if (count == 0) printf("Please enter a number first.\n\n");
        else
            avg = total / count;
            printf("The average is %.2f\n\n", avg);
        break;
    case 'E':
        printf("You entered %i numbers.\n\n", count);
        break;
    case 'Q':
        printf("Thanks for playing.\n\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Invalid Selection.\n\n");
        break;
    }
    pause;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using a while loop?

Comment: SO is not here to solve your homework. A hint though - if you want the program to repeat you will need some sort of loop, in this case probably a `while` loop

Comment: search google for "while loop in c"

Comment: @CIsForCoocckies I tried a do while, I had do at the beginning, and then after all the cases I had while (choice != ____) idk what to put there

Answer (score 0):

You would need to include another while loop encapsulating your switch statement

```
bool running = 1;

while(running)
{
    printf("Enter your selection: ");
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        ...
        case 'q':
        case 'Q':
            running = 0;
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%c", &again);` --> `scanf(" %c", &again);`.   (add space).

Without that space, after entering <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `num` will consume the `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'`, but leave the `'\n'` for `"%c"`.  By adding a white-space before `"%c"`, `scanf()` will first consume any white-space before assigning a `char` to `again`.

```
  scanf("%i", &num);
  ...
  printf("Do you want to enter another number? (Y/N):  ");
  // scanf("%c", &again);
  scanf(" %c", &again);
} while (again != 'N');
```